# Why "go build/run" does not recognize the types that are defined in separate files but the same folder and belong to the same package

Tags: go, visual-studio-code, vscode-debugger

I'm new to golang and could not find a good answer.

Problem: I have two files in the same folder that belong to the main package called `main.go` and `my_type.go`. The former includes main func and uses the type defined in the second file. The type is just a simple string array i.e. `type myType [] string`. Now if I understand correctly, types and funcs belonging to the same package don't need imports and by convention are started with lower case letters. This said, `go run/build main.go` spits out the error "undefined" for the type. The only way it works is by specifying both files or use a wild card. Is this the expected behavior? I've also started using vs.code and wonder if there's a way to configure running this properly in vs.code

Thanks in advance!

Sample error:

```
go build main.go
# command-line-arguments
./main.go:17:11: undefined: myType
```

Comment: `go build main.go` only attempts to build `main.go`, which doesn't include `my_type.go`. You need to build both files, either with `go build main.go my_type.go`, or preferably just `go build` from the root directory.

Answer (score 0):

I would just use `go build` alone as follows

```
example> dir
19/05/2023  19:50               146 main.go
19/05/2023  19:48                39 mytype.go
```

```
example> type main.go
package main
import (
        "fmt"
)
func main() {
        var a myType
        a = append(a, "foo")
        a = append(a, "bar")
        fmt.Printf("%#v\n", a)
}
```

```
example> type mytype.go
package main
type myType  []string
```

```
example> go mod init
go: creating new go.mod: module example
go: to add module requirements and sums:
        go mod tidy

example> go mod tidy
example> go build
example> example
main.myType{"foo", "bar"}
```

If you just specify `go build main.go` it won't take into account the other file.

You can also try `go run main.go mytype.go` but I habitually just use either `go build` or `go install`. I typically have a separate directory per project executable.